# sed for each empty line or match increment field

Tags: awk, sed

Example of data generated by software binary:

```
Label 1: "AAA"
Label 2: "BBB"
Label 3: "CCC"

Label 1: "XXX"
Label 2: "YYY"
Label 3: "ZZZ"
```

Each label "group" is separated by new line or starting with `"Label 1"`, can have `n` groups (so need to get `lab, lab2, lab3` in desired output and so on).

Current output:

```
lab,Label 1,AAA,
lab,Label 2,BBB,
lab,Label 3,CCC,
lab,Label 1,XXX,
lab,Label 2,YYY,
lab,Label 3,ZZZ,
```

Existing code:

```
labels="$(${binary} -list | sed -e '/^$/d')"
echo "$labels" | sed -e 's/: \{1,\}/,/g' -e 's/"//g' -e 's/, /,/g' -e "s|^|lab,|g" -e 's/$/,/g'
```

Desired output:

```
lab,Label 1,AAA,
lab,Label 2,BBB,
lab,Label 3,CCC,
lab2,Label 1,XXX,
lab2,Label 2,YYY,
lab2,Label 3,ZZZ,
```

Comment: You want to convert the items to csv with a new col 1 containing the string "lab" appended with a number indicating its grouping in the original file (except for the first group, displayed without a number). Is that right?

Comment: Since you want to modify one of the fields based on the group number, I think `sed` is the wrong tool here (no arithmetic possible in sed). You could use something like `awk`, or `perl` or `ruby`.

Comment: @Dave Pritlove that's right with simple transformation to remove spaces or quotes. Each group is separated by empty line (or "Label 1" is always first in the group).  There can be multiple empty lines at the end of listing (of all groups) so need to discard them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since an empty line is record separator, here is a way to do this in `awk` using empty `RS`:

```bash
awk -v RS= '{
   gsub(/(^|\n)/, "&lab" (NR>1?NR:"") ","); gsub(/(: )?"/, ",")
} 1' file

lab,Label 1,AAA,
lab,Label 2,BBB,
lab,Label 3,CCC,
lab2,Label 1,XXX,
lab2,Label 2,YYY,
lab2,Label 3,ZZZ,
```

Comment: You cannot get it cleaner than this!

Comment: Thank you, end up using this variant as it's pretty clear!

Answer (score 1):

`awk` is probably a better choice here:

```
awk -F': "|"' -v OFS=, '$1=="Label 1" {p="lab"n; n+=n?1:2} /./{print p,$1,$2,""}'
```

Declare the input field separator as either `: "` or `"` (`-F': "|"'`) and the output field separator as a comma (`-v OFS=,`). If the first field of the current line is `"Label 1"`, set variable `p` to concatenation of `"lab"` and value of variable `n`, if `n` is defined increment it by 1, else by 2. Finally, if the current line is not empty (`/./`) print `p`, the first and second fields, and an empty last field (for the trailing comma), separated by `OFS`.

Note: uninitialized variables (like `n`) evaluate as the empty string or numeric value 0, depending on the evaluation context. Here, in `p="lab"n`, the evaluation context of `n` is string concatenation. So the first time `n` is evaluated as empty string and `p` takes value `"lab"`. The other times `n` has value 2, 3, 4... and `p` takes values `"lab2"`, `"lab3"`, `"lab4"`...

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -v OFS=',' '
    NF { gsub(/(: )?"/,OFS); print "lab" n, $0; next }
    { n += (n ? 1 : 2) }
' file
lab,Label 1,AAA,
lab,Label 2,BBB,
lab,Label 3,CCC,
lab2,Label 1,XXX,
lab2,Label 2,YYY,
lab2,Label 3,ZZZ,
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code.

```
awk -v OFS="," '
!NF{
  if(initCount==""){ initCount=2 }
  else             { initCount++ }
  next
}
{
  gsub(/: "/,",")
  sub(/"$/,",")
  print "lab"initCount,$0
}
'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

I will first transmute your code into GNU `AWK` and then apply changes to make it work as intended, let `file.txt` content be

```
Label 1: "AAA"
Label 2: "BBB"
Label 3: "CCC"

Label 1: "XXX"
Label 2: "YYY"
Label 3: "ZZZ"
```

then

```
awk '!/^$/{gsub(/: +/,",");gsub(/"/,"");gsub(/, /,",");gsub(/^/,"lab,");gsub(/$/,",");print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
lab,Label 1,AAA,
lab,Label 2,BBB,
lab,Label 3,CCC,
lab,Label 1,XXX,
lab,Label 2,YYY,
lab,Label 3,ZZZ,
```

note that I kept all substitution global, even though `^` and `$` might give at most 1 substitution each.

We need counter, which would increase when `Label 1:` is in line and which could be used during replacement, this can be done following way

```
awk '/Label 1:/{cnt+=1}!/^$/{gsub(/: +/,",");gsub(/"/,"");gsub(/, /,",");gsub(/^/,"lab" (cnt>1?cnt:"") ",");gsub(/$/,",");print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
lab,Label 1,AAA,
lab,Label 2,BBB,
lab,Label 3,CCC,
lab2,Label 1,XXX,
lab2,Label 2,YYY,
lab2,Label 3,ZZZ,
```

Explanation: If there is `Label 1:` in line increase `cnt` by 1, if it is not yet set assume 0 and then increase, for not (`!`) empty line (`/^$/`) execute substitutions and `print`, for 4th gsub use `lab` followed by cnt if cnt above 1 else empty string followed by `,`.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo '
Label 1: "AAA"
Label 2: "BBB"
Label 3: "CCC"

Label 1: "XXX"
Label 2: "YYY"
Label 3: "ZZZ"' |
```

---

```
mawk 'NF ? $1 = (__)_ OFS $1 : (_+=!_)<_++' FS='(: )?"' OFS=, __='lab'
```

---

```
lab,Label 1,AAA,
lab,Label 2,BBB,
lab,Label 3,CCC,
lab2,Label 1,XXX,
lab2,Label 2,YYY,
lab2,Label 3,ZZZ,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F': *"|"' '
  /^Label 1:/{i++} 
  !/^$/{printf("lab%s,%s,%s,\n", (i==1 ? "" : i), $1, $2)}
' file
lab,Label 1,AAA,
lab,Label 2,BBB,
lab,Label 3,CCC,
lab2,Label 1,XXX,
lab2,Label 2,YYY,
lab2,Label 3,ZZZ,

$ awk -F': *"|"' -v OFS="," '
  /^Label 1:/{i++} 
  !/^$/{$1=$1; print (i==1 ? "lab" : "lab"i), $0}
' file
lab,Label 1,AAA,
lab,Label 2,BBB,
lab,Label 3,CCC,
lab2,Label 1,XXX,
lab2,Label 2,YYY,
lab2,Label 3,ZZZ,
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;$!{N;/\n$/!ba}
        y/"/,/;s/: |\n$//g;s/^/lab%,/mg;G
        :b;s/lab%(.*)\n(.*)/lab$((\2+1))\1\n\2/;tb
        s/(.*)\n.*/echo "\1"/e;s/^lab1,/lab,/mg
        x;s/.*/echo $((&+1))/e;x' file
```

Gather up groups of labels.

Translate `"`'s to commas.

Remove `:` 's and the empty line. Prepend `lab%` to each line and then append the hold space to the current batch of labels.

Replace each occurrence of the introduced `%`  by a shell computation using the value stored in the hold space.

Replace the pattern space by an echo command that replaces the shell computations by an actual label number.

For the first set of labels remove the actual label number i.e. remove `1`.

Prepare the hold space for the next batch of labels.

Print the result.

Alternative:

```
sed -E '/\S/{=;G;s/(.*)\n(.*)/echo "s#^#lab$((\2+1)),#"/e;b}
        x;s/.*/echo "$((&+1))"/e;x;=;s/.*/d/' file |
sed 'N;s/\n//' |
sed -f - -e 's/^lab1,/lab,/;s/: //;y/"/,/' file
```

Generate a sed script that amends/deletes each line of the input file.